# Apply formula at dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have data frame (df) where I want to apply formula `(x - df[14]) / (df[(length(df)] - df[14])` and store new values in new columns in data frame (df)

INPUT

```
chr start   end strand  ref.bam bam1    bam2    bam3    bam4    bam5    bam6    bam7    length  fpkm_bam1   fpkm_bam2   fpkm_bam3   fpkm_bam4   fpkm_bam5   fpkm_bam6   fpkm_bam7
chr15   97054158    97056002    -   2473    7   4   21  50  220 365 903 1844    0.139   0.232   0.578   1.925   8.128   22.589  139.477
chr2    152142874   152145506   -   2451    13  10  31  56  239 379 1045    2632    0.181   0.406   0.598   1.51    6.187   16.433  113.085
chr10   4265251 4268452 -   2407    28  5   32  68  249 426 933 3201    0.321   0.167   0.507   1.508   5.3 15.188  83.018
chr2    165810215   165813098   -   2187    4   2   37  44  138 263 629 2883    0.051   0.074   0.651   1.083   3.261   10.411  62.141
chr2    153648903   153651359   -   2032    20  2   27  74  219 279 784 2456    0.299   0.087   0.558   2.139   6.075   12.964  90.921
chr9    57260833    57263089    -   2026    22  12  19  69  151 354 732 2256    0.358   0.569   0.427   2.171   4.56    17.908  92.416
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
chr start   end strand  ref.bam bam1    bam2    bam3    bam4    bam5    bam6    bam7    length  fpkm_bam1   fpkm_bam2   fpkm_bam3   fpkm_bam4   fpkm_bam5   fpkm_bam6   fpkm_bam7   scaled_fpkm_bam1    scaled_fpkm_bam2    scaled_fpkm_bam3    scaled_fpkm_bam4    scaled_fpkm_bam5    scaled_fpkm_bam6    scaled_fpkm_bam7
chr15   97054158    97056002    -   2473    7   4   21  50  220 365 903 1844    0.139   0.232   0.578   1.925   8.128   22.589  139.477 0   0.001   0.003   0.013   0.057   0.161   1
chr2    152142874   152145506   -   2451    13  10  31  56  239 379 1045    2632    0.181   0.406   0.598   1.51    6.187   16.433  113.085 0   0.002   0.004   0.012   0.053   0.144   1
chr10   4265251 4268452 -   2407    28  5   32  68  249 426 933 3201    0.321   0.167   0.507   1.508   5.3 15.188  83.018  0   -0.002  0.002   0.014   0.06    0.18    1
chr2    165810215   165813098   -   2187    4   2   37  44  138 263 629 2883    0.051   0.074   0.651   1.083   3.261   10.411  62.141  0   0   0.01    0.017   0.052   0.167   1
chr2    153648903   153651359   -   2032    20  2   27  74  219 279 784 2456    0.299   0.087   0.558   2.139   6.075   12.964  90.921  0   -0.002  0.003   0.02    0.064   0.14    1
chr9    57260833    57263089    -   2026    22  12  19  69  151 354 732 2256    0.358   0.569   0.427   2.171   4.56    17.908  92.416  0   0.002   0.001   0.02    0.046   0.191   1
```

i have tried this

```
df %>% mutate(across(contains("fpkm"), ~ (.x - df[14])/ (df[length(df)] - df[14]) , .names = "scaled_{.col}"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to extract the column as vector, use `[[`, instead of `[` (as it returns still a data.frame with a single column.  In addition, `df[[14]]` works fine if the data is not grouped, but in grouped data, this can be  troublesome.  Use either `pick` or `cur_data()`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(contains("fpkm"),
   ~ (.x - cur_data()[[14]])/
        (cur_data()[[length(df)]]- cur_data()[[14]]) , .names = "scaled_{.col}"))
```

-output

```
df
 chr     start       end strand ref.bam bam1 bam2 bam3 bam4 bam5 bam6 bam7 length fpkm_bam1 fpkm_bam2 fpkm_bam3 fpkm_bam4
1 chr15  97054158  97056002      -    2473    7    4   21   50  220  365  903   1844     0.139     0.232     0.578     1.925
2  chr2 152142874 152145506      -    2451   13   10   31   56  239  379 1045   2632     0.181     0.406     0.598     1.510
3 chr10   4265251   4268452      -    2407   28    5   32   68  249  426  933   3201     0.321     0.167     0.507     1.508
4  chr2 165810215 165813098      -    2187    4    2   37   44  138  263  629   2883     0.051     0.074     0.651     1.083
5  chr2 153648903 153651359      -    2032   20    2   27   74  219  279  784   2456     0.299     0.087     0.558     2.139
6  chr9  57260833  57263089      -    2026   22   12   19   69  151  354  732   2256     0.358     0.569     0.427     2.171
  fpkm_bam5 fpkm_bam6 fpkm_bam7 scaled_fpkm_bam1 scaled_fpkm_bam2 scaled_fpkm_bam3 scaled_fpkm_bam4 scaled_fpkm_bam5
1     8.128    22.589   139.477                0     0.0006674418     0.0031506122       0.01281775       0.05733540
2     6.187    16.433   113.085                0     0.0019928435     0.0036934032       0.01177106       0.05319564
3     5.300    15.188    83.018                0    -0.0018622199     0.0022491747       0.01435360       0.06020775
4     3.261    10.411    62.141                0     0.0003704300     0.0096633919       0.01662103       0.05169915
5     6.075    12.964    90.921                0    -0.0023393878     0.0028580256       0.02030412       0.06373728
6     4.560    17.908    92.416                0     0.0022920333     0.0007495275       0.01969411       0.04564514
  scaled_fpkm_bam6 scaled_fpkm_bam7
1        0.1611190                1
2        0.1439453                1
3        0.1797768                1
4        0.1668546                1
5        0.1397564                1
6        0.1906407                1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(chr = c("chr15", "chr2", "chr10", "chr2", "chr2", 
"chr9"), start = c(97054158L, 152142874L, 4265251L, 165810215L, 
153648903L, 57260833L), end = c(97056002L, 152145506L, 4268452L, 
165813098L, 153651359L, 57263089L), strand = c("-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-"), ref.bam = c(2473L, 2451L, 2407L, 2187L, 2032L, 
2026L), bam1 = c(7L, 13L, 28L, 4L, 20L, 22L), bam2 = c(4L, 10L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 12L), bam3 = c(21L, 31L, 32L, 37L, 27L, 19L), bam4 = c(50L, 
56L, 68L, 44L, 74L, 69L), bam5 = c(220L, 239L, 249L, 138L, 219L, 
151L), bam6 = c(365L, 379L, 426L, 263L, 279L, 354L), bam7 = c(903L, 
1045L, 933L, 629L, 784L, 732L), length = c(1844L, 2632L, 3201L, 
2883L, 2456L, 2256L), fpkm_bam1 = c(0.139, 0.181, 0.321, 0.051, 
0.299, 0.358), fpkm_bam2 = c(0.232, 0.406, 0.167, 0.074, 0.087, 
0.569), fpkm_bam3 = c(0.578, 0.598, 0.507, 0.651, 0.558, 0.427
), fpkm_bam4 = c(1.925, 1.51, 1.508, 1.083, 2.139, 2.171), fpkm_bam5 = c(8.128, 
6.187, 5.3, 3.261, 6.075, 4.56), fpkm_bam6 = c(22.589, 16.433, 
15.188, 10.411, 12.964, 17.908), fpkm_bam7 = c(139.477, 113.085, 
83.018, 62.141, 90.921, 92.416)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```